# おきばりになさって！ with the meaning of 頑張れ！

Tags: idioms, interjections

I was discussing with my Japanese colleagues about expressions peculiar to contemporary bourgeoisie.
One expression I already knew was `ご機嫌よう!`, meaning `またね!`.

My question is about another one: `おきばりになさって！`, meaning `頑張れ！` according to them.
Apparently it can be heard at [certain](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%B1%E6%B4%8B%E8%8B%B1%E5%92%8C%E5%A5%B3%E5%AD%A6%E9%99%A2%E4%B8%AD%E5%AD%A6%E9%83%A8%E3%83%BB%E9%AB%98%E7%AD%89%E9%83%A8) sport competitions, said to お嬢様s by her mothers.

Surprisingly enough, Google has [no results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8D%E3%81%B0%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%22) for this expression. How can it be?

- Did I misspell the expression? I am pretty sure my colleague said that, though.
- Is it so rare that even Google does not know about it?

Comment: I've never heard it before but you can it here http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8D%E3%81%B0%E3%82%8A%E3%82%84%E3%81%99

Comment: 「おきばりになって」か「おきばりなさって」では？（どっちもあんま使わないけど）

Answer (score 3):

@Choko has the answer, it seems that the correct expression is:

> おきばりなさって

Some more examples:

> ほな、あんじょうおきばりなさってサービスの練習しとくなはれ！

(http://fresco.blog.tennis365.net/archives/day/20101222.html)

> みなさんも新年度っすてきにおきばりなさってくださいね

(http://www.tv-asahi.co.jp/reading/sanpo_hagino/date/2012/04/01/)

Comment: 京都弁では高貴で丁寧な表現としても使われる（「おきばりやす」「きばりなはれ」）と知ってはいますが、稀だと思います。大阪弁などでは"気張る"はむしろラフな表現だと思います（「おい、こら、きばれや！」）。関東に来てからはほとんど聞いたことがないです。